# Building MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

Since the MVVMCross repository (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross) has quite a few useful examples to take a deeper look at I tried cloning and building it which didnt really work out well:
Every project has yellow warning signs next to its dependencies

As soon as I try to run a NuGet Package Restore I get the following error:

> Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The operation failed as details for project MvvmCross.Forms could not be loaded.

Cleaning any of the projects inside the solution leads to the following error:

> Error MSB4057 The target "Clean" does not exist in the project.   MvvmCross.Plugin.Location   F:\MvvmCross\MvvmCross.Plugins\Location\MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.csproj    1

So far I arleady tried the following:

1. Move the solution folder to a shorter path (F:\MvvmCross)
2. Uninstall unneeded .net Core SDK (now I have installed: .NET Core
   SDK 1.0.4 (x64), .NET Core SDK 1.1.0 (x64), Microsoft .NET Core SDK
   2.1.301 (x64), Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.301 (x86))
3. Updated Visual Studio to the latest solution (15.7.4)

I also attached a build log for the MVVMCross project (https://gist.github.com/Zz9uk3/1b96eebbe3c0466efecd1375515a114a). In the logfile it appears that I am not connected to a Mac while I am for sure connected.

Does anyone have some directions on how to build the whole MVVMCross project properly? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Which branch are you trying to build? Are you building in VS or are you using the build script?

Comment: I am using VS and I am trying to build the master branch.

I am reinstalling VS right now. Maybe something about my installation is corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling netcore and all other VS components and then reinstalling solved it (for whatever reason).